# Is there a way to store Only date in SQLite with time 00:00:00

Tags: c#, sqlite

### Currently I am using C# with SQLite.

***Scenario :***

I see the date saved in DB as "2017-01-01 22:36:24.3783231". I want to save only date with no specific time, it can be 00:00:00 though.

how can I do it?

***Expected Output is:***

"2017-01-01 00:00:00"

------------------------EDITED---------------------

the datatype for 'date' column is DATE and I simple use Dapper to insert Column as DateTime.Now utility.

------------------------EDITED 2nd-----------------

I also want the dynamic dates(any dates) chosen from DateTimePicker to be in same format.

Comment: What is the code used to store that date?

Comment: If you don't need it, why bother setting it to 0?

Comment: you can send the date formatted from your code to SQLite. Please post code

Comment: Simply use `yourDateTimeValue.Date` instead of `yourDateTimeValue`.

Answer (score 2):

Just guessing because I don't know how you add this to your database;
If you want to save the current date, without the timestamp, you can get DateTime.Today instead of DateTime.Now.

Comment: What you suggested is only for today's date, what about dynamic date?

Comment: @Peter your answer is wrong. I don't know how people upvoted it. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.today(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @Peter DateTime.Today will also output with time. You need to format it before storing it.

Comment: @Prabu; The question states 'I want to save only date with no specific time, it can be 00:00:00 though. '

So, DateTime.Today will return 00:00:00, which is OK according to the topic starter

Comment: @Peter R it will also include the time.Check the link I mentioned.DateTime.Today will give you the exact date and system time.

Comment: @Prabu Yes I know 'An object that is set to today's date, with the time component set to 00:00:00.'

This was not an issue according to the question asked by Ankur. He stated time could be set, but it should be all zero's.

Answer (score 0):

Well I solved my issue using below peice of code in c# as below;

```
DateTime.ParseExact(dateTransaction.Value.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"), "yyyy-MM-dd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture); // dateTransaction is DatePicker.
```

Below is the proof of snapshot that is has started working as expected.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can Use DateOnly Type or DataType(DataType.Date) annotation for your Property.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

You can extract date from the **timestamp** using this code.

```
DateTime dt = DateTime.ParseExact("yourdate","ddMMyyyy",CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
```

Use this output to store in database.

`dateTimePicker1.Value.Date` you can use this store only the date.

Comment: I am using Dapper to store the field in DateTime only. Your solution converts it to string. Well, @Peter has suggested a correct way to me. you can read it.

Comment: good example of bad practice - using `Substring` would be cheaper way. I think the OP doesn't expect a string result

Comment: you can pass this output to datetime to get the desire result